# Is it possible in Liferay to add custom Resource-Actions to my portlet?

Tags: permissions, action, liferay, portal

I create my portlet with Liferay (sdk 6.1), by deploy the portlet gets some default resource-actions, but I need some actions more. Because I want implement some complex permission based portlet. And I don't want create a Ext-Plugin to customize '../resource-actions/default.xml'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see [this liferay wiki post](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Permissioning+in+Plugin+Environment) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536976/where-to-place-resource-action-mapping-in-liferay-portlet). If you did and those were not helpful please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own user action permissions on the portlet you have created. This code will come to the rescue:

```
ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(),"portlet_name",ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL,(String)Iframe_prim_key, new String[]{ActionKeys.VIEW});
```

[Check the same at this link](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11404408)