# How to prevent user delete their approved web content in Liferay?

Tags: liferay

I have a situation like :
- User A post a Web Content 1---> Get Approved to show it on the page
- By default, user A can delete Web Content 1 (status is Aprroved or not)

How can  i prevent user A so that he can't delete Web Content 1 which is approved by reviewer ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Change the permissions given to the user, on that portlet. Permissions can be set [as explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445894/is-it-possible-in-liferay-to-add-custom-resource-actions-to-my-portlet/9462621#9462621)